# HTML href tag adding a '#!' to fragment

Tags: html, angularjs, web, hyperlink

I'm looking to redirect to a certian fragment of my page by using an anchor tag in HTML.

So far, I have

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#Links">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

as the link, and then later in the code

```
<section id = "Links">
    ...
</section>
```

However, when I click on the anchor when testing on my localhost, the URL becomes

http://localhost:5000/#!#Links

Rather than

http://localhost:5000/#Links

Why is this? How can I eliminate the shebang from the URL after I click on the link?

Additionally, my webapp is using AngularJS. I don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<a href="#Links">
  <section ..>
    ...
  </section>
</a>

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:5000/#Links">Links</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: This still has the same issue, and does not work if I want to migrate from localhost

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It was because I was using angularJS. Instead, I did

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#Links" target="_self">Links</a></li>
</ul>

<section id = "Links" target="_self">
    ...
</section>
```